# Give number one to a left page without making it a right page

Tags: page-numbering, double-sided

I'm writing my Master's Thesis as a two-sided document which starts chapters on odd pages on the right. However before the first chapter begins, I would like to have a pair of pages facing each other, the left one starting with number one. But when I set this page to one via `\setcounter{page}{1}`, LaTeX makes it to a right page with the margin on the right. And finally, as the minimal example shows, when starting the real chapter, the blank page on the left is missing, which is probalby will fix itself when the problem above is fixed.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, openright,draft]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\title{right page, as expected}
\maketitle

\begingroup
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{}
\renewcommand{\clearpage}{}

\chapter*{Abstract}
right page but it should be a left page, numbered with I

\newpage
\chapter*{Zusammenfassung} 
left page but it should be a right page, numbered with II
\endgroup

\cleardoublepage
\chapter{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
Right page starting with number 1, as expected but blank page missing

\end{document}
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can change the even pages to being left pages just within the group?

Comment: Is it a requirement from your institution? Nothing can surprise me any more. `;-)`

Comment: No, it's my own Idea. I like it when you have both abstracts (english and german) on facing pages because they belong together. However It's strange to start the first page with 2 ;)

Comment: No, the first page is the title page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell LaTeX it is a right page by adding one to the page number, but showing the page number you want.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, openright,draft]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\title{right page, as expected}
\maketitle

\clearpage

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{}
\renewcommand{\clearpage}{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\@Roman{\numexpr\value{page}-1}}
\makeatother
\setcounter{page}{2}

\chapter*{Abstract}
Left page, numbered with I

\newpage
\chapter*{Zusammenfassung} 
Right page, numbered with II

\newpage
\endgroup

\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}
Right page starting with number 1, as expected, with the blank page.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, impressive simple solution. How does it work and what literatue helps to develop such solution by myself? ;) 

Thanks for the fast help

Comment: Oh no, now I noticed that the ToC which goes in my thesis over two sites and starts on the left, as it is in the ` \begingroup ... \toc ... \endgrop` has the numbers III and V (IV is missing).

Comment: @Thesiswriter Use `\tableofcontents\newpage` to get the IV on the second page of the toc. But with a KOMA-Script class there is no need to redefine `\clearpage` and `\cleardoublepage`. You could use `\begingroup\KOMAoptions{open=any}<contents>\clearpage\endgroup`.

Comment: @esdd:
perfect, thanks. But why does this affect the page numbering as I would expect the newpage to be added after the toc and not in between?

Comment: You have to add the `\newpage` (or `\clearpage`) before the group is closed by `\endgroup`.