# How to remove the \cleardoublepage within \mainmatter in KOMA Script

Tags: koma-script, scrbook, clearpage

My understanding is that the `\mainmatter` command contains `\cleardoublepage`.
I want the First Chapter to begin on the very next page following the end of "Intro 2" with no blank pages in between them, There are currently two blank pages, at least one of which is due to `\mainmatter`.

The other blank page seems to be due to

```
\makeatletter
\@openrightfalse
\makeatother
```

,which I use so that "Intro 2" immediately follows "Intro 1" with no blank page. But resetting this back to normal with

```
\makeatletter
\@openrighttrue
\makeatother
```

doesn't help my problem.

The command of `\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage` also hasn't helped me. An alternate command that does not clear any pages might be helpful here.

The following MWE yields two blank pages in between Intro 2 and the First Chapter. I want there to be zero blank pages.

**MWE:**

```
%XeLaTeX
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[
    inner=0.5in,
    outer=0.5in,
    twoside,
    showframe
    ]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\addchap{intro 1}
\lipsum[1]

%make chapter open on left-side (or any side)
%reset it before the next chapter
\makeatletter
\@openrightfalse
\makeatother

\addchap{intro 2}
\lipsum[2-14]

%reset to opening chapter on right-side
%\makeatletter
%\@openrighttrue
%\makeatother

%\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{open=left}%I need all chapters from now on to start on left page
\mainmatter

\chapter{First Chapter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The original definition of `\mainmatter` in  class `scrbook` is

```latex
\newcommand*\mainmatter{%
  \if@twoside\cleardoubleoddpage\else\clearpage\fi
  \@mainmattertrue\pagenumbering{arabic}%
}
```

`\pagenumbering{arabic}` resets the page counter to 1. This is an odd number and odd page numbers must be on a right pages. Therefore `\cleardoubleoddpage` is used to ensure that the page with the odd page number 1 is a right page. So it is not possible to start main matter with page number 1 on a left page.

So if you want to use `\mainmatter` in a twosided document with chapters starting on left pages, there will be at least one blank page (the right page with odd number 1) before the first chapter in main matter.

---

You could redefine `\mainmatter` to use `\clearpage` and not change the pagenumbering system:

```latex
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\mainmatter{%
  \clearpage
  \@mainmattertrue
}
\makeatother
```

If there should be arabic page numbers in the document, then you can use `\frontmatter\pagenumbering{arabic}` or redefine `\frontmatter` too:

```latex
\renewcommand*{\frontmatter}{%
  \if@twoside\cleardoubleoddpage\else\clearpage\fi
  \@mainmatterfalse
}
```

But do you really need `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`?

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[
  inner=0.5in,
  outer=0.5in,
  twoside,
  showframe
  ]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\frontmatter}{%
  %\if@twoside\cleardoubleoddpage\else\clearpage\fi
  %\@mainmatterfalse
%}
%\renewcommand*\mainmatter{%
  %\clearpage
  %\@mainmattertrue
%}
%\makeatother

\begin{document}
%\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\addchap{intro 1}
\lipsum[1]

\KOMAoptions{open=any}% make chapter open on any side
\addchap{intro 2}
\lipsum[2-14]
%\KOMAoptions{open=right}% reset to opening chapter on right-side

\KOMAoptions{open=left}%I need all chapters from now on to start on left page
%\mainmatter
\chapter{First Chapter}
\end{document}
```

---

You could also redefine `\mainmatter` to start on an even page. Then you must change the page number of the first page in main matter to an even number, eg 0 or 2. But then there is page with number 0 or page 1 is missing ... Ugly. So I do not recommend the following code snippet

```latex
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\mainmatter{%
  \cleardoubleevenpage
  \@mainmattertrue\pagenumbering{arabic}%
  \setcounter{page}{0}% or another even page number
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: How can I use your first version but also have arabic page numbering? As of now, the `\frontmatter` roman numberings flows into the main matter, and of course with your second version the page number starts at 0 or 2.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: I lose roman page numbering if I remove `frontmatter`, so that's one reason I have it.

Comment: If the roman page v should be followed by the arabic page 6, then you can add `\renewcommand\thepage{\arabic{page}}` to the redefinition of `\mainmatter`. But I am not sure what your desired result is. Note again, left pages must have even page numbers.

Comment: I want a left page to start the page counting, i.e., page 1. I think this answer contains a solution that could be incorporated here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270266/121944